# Modal Popup con Bootstrap en asp.net no se muestra

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, bootstrap

estoy intentado crea un modal popup con Bootstrap en asp.net pero no consigo que se muestre, pondré mi código

**MasterPage**

Estoy usando una MasterPage porque en ella estoy cargando un menú de opciones pero solo pondré el código de lo que necesito para no hacer esto tan extenso esto

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css' media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 function ShowPopup(title, body) 
 {
  $("#Popup .modal-title").html(title);
  $("#Popup .modal-body").html(body);
  $("#Popup").modal("show") 
  }
</script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 <body id="page-top">
<form runat="server">
 <div id="wrapper"> 
     <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left:350px">  

        <div id="Popup" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
```

**index.aspx**

Tengo una página aspx donde estoy creando un formulario para realizar la carga de un archivo

```
    <div id="content-wrapper" class="auto-style2">
     <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="#">Logo</a>
        </li>
         <asp:label ID="Menu" class="breadcrumb-item active" runat="server"></asp:label> 
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active"></li>
     </ol>
        <br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" Width="632px"  CssClass="auto-style3" Enabled="true" EnableTheming="True" />
        <br />     
        <asp:Button ID="btnvisualizarArchivo" cssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Visualizar" OnClick="visualizarArchivo_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCargarArchivo" cssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Cargar" OnClick="CargarArchivo_Click" data-target="#Popup"  />
        <br />          
        <br />
        <br />
        <div style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y:hidden">
        <asp:GridView ID="grdEjemplo" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left" Width="860px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdEjemplo_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="4" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed small-top-margin" >
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid-header" BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True"  ForeColor="White" Font-Size="small" />
            <PagerSettings FirstPageText="" LastPageText="" PageButtonCount="4" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" Font-Size="Small" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
        </asp:GridView>
         </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        </div>
```

**index.cs**

```
 protected void CargarArchivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  executeSP(); 
 }

    public void executeSP()
    {
        SqlDataReader dataReader;
        string message = "";
        try
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Process_MenuWEB", con);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandTimeout = 3600;

                SqlParameter parameter1 = command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                parameter1.Value = idUpload.ToString();

                SqlParameter parameter2 = command.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                parameter2.Value = Session["UserId"].ToString();

                dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    message = message +  dataReader["Observation"].ToString() + "//n";
                }

                string title = "Resultado de la transacción";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + title + "', '" + message + "');", true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogging(ex);
        }
    }
```

Mi idea es que al darle en el botón cargar se ejecute un procedimiento almacenado el cual me puede devolver un mensaje de éxito o varios errores que igualmente se deben mostrar, y quiero mostrar eso en el popup pero no se muestra lo que hace es recargar la página nuevamente y ya, cual sería la manera correcta de solucionar este problema ? Es mejor crear otra página que solo contenga el popup y llamarla como un formulario popup ?

Comment: Probaste ejecutar ShowPopup desde el cliente directamente para ver si loo abre?

Comment: O sea crear el Popup en el index.aspx ?

Comment: no no, osea en el load de tu pagina o agrega un botón de prueba con  onclick="ShowPopup('test title', 'test body')" para ver si el realmente funciona.

Comment: Probé lo que me dijiste desde el Load de la página y no funciono y la probarlo en el botón me tira un error de compilación